# Necessary condition for a graph to be Non-Hamiltonian

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics

Let us denote the edges incident on vertices of valence 2 as "required" as these edges has to be covered by a Hamiltonian circuit, if one exists on that (undirected) graph. Given a graph on which a proper subset of the "required" edges along with two edges incident on a vertex of valency $\geq 3$ form a cycle, can anything related to the Hamiltonicity of the graph be claimed? A few basic rules for the existence of Hamiltonian Cycles is listed here: http://www.mit.edu/~miforbes/ham_cycle.pdf  Can rule (4) be extended in any way to answer this query?

Comment: Isn't your question answered in these notes you link to? Rule (4) seems to address you question exactly as it is. If there is a non-Hamiltonian cycle formed by required edges, the graph cannot be Hamiltonian.

Comment: crossposted on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/45272/necessary-condition-for-a-graph-to-be-non-hamiltonian

Comment: @ Karolina No, it does not. My constraint is " Given a graph on which a PROPER SUBSET of the "required" edges form a cycle"

Comment: Ok, but that still means, that the graph cannot be Hamitonian - you use rule (5), which gives you some non-Hamiltonian cycle of vertices of degree 2, and you have to use all edges of it.

Comment: @ Suresh Venkat : Is crossposting not allowed?

Comment: @Esha: Regarding crossposting, please see this part of our FAQ.  The point is to avoid people on different sites doing double work: http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/225/official-faq-for-theoretical-computer-science/231#231

Comment: Ok.. Thanks and sorry about this. Won't do it in future.

Comment: @Esha: the easiest is to include all other urls where you have posted the same question. Secondly, if this or your previous postings is homework or some project you're doing, I also think it is good style to reference the cstheory discussions where you got valuable information from.

Comment: MO Link: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/45272/necessary-condition-for-a-graph-to-be-non-hamiltonian

Answer (score 1):

Asking whether a graph is non-Hamiltonian is CoNP-Complete so it is doubtful that such an algorithm exists.

If you are satisfied with a heuristic that provides a certificates of non-Hamiltonicity, see [Bondy and Murty's](http://www.ecp6.jussieu.fr/pageperso/bondy/books/gtwa/pdf/chapter4.pdf) [book](http://www.ecp6.jussieu.fr/pageperso/bondy/books/gtwa/gtwa.html) (page 53) for a sufficient, but not necessary, condition for non-Hamiltonicity:  If $G$ is Hamiltonian then, for every nonempty subset, $S$, of $V$:

$$ \omega(G - S) \le |S| $$

Where $\omega(G - S)$ is the number of connected components left in $G$ after removing the vertices in $S$.  A simple counterexample for the converse is the [peterson graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph): It passes the above test but is not Hamiltonian.

Comment: I don't believe that CoNP-complete is significant here. The reason is that the property cannot be used as a certificate, since it cannot be applied to any graph. It may be possible that Non-Hamiltonicity is in P for this restricted family of inputs.